# Sections: automatically derive short title from title

Tags: table-of-contents, sectioning

I have a document with very long section titles which span multiple lines (potential exam questions). I'd like to restrict them to one line in the table of contents.

I just found out that this is easy to achieve manually by providing a short title, e.g., `\subsection[Short Title]{Title}`. However, I'd like to automatize this. I'm pretty sure that it's easy to redefine `\subsection` etc. to automatically set the respective short title, I'm just not adept enough to come up with this myself.

Example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\section{What I have}

\subsection{This is an insanely long subsection title that is supposed to span multiple lines, which it does because it's insanely long}
\subsubsection{This is a similarly long subsubsection title that should also span more than one line, which it does as it's very long}

\section{What I want}

\subsection[This is an insanely long subsection title that is supposed to span\ldots]{This is an insanely long subsection title that is supposed to span multiple lines, which it does because it's insanely long}
\subsubsection[This is a similarly long subsubsection title that should\ldots]{This is a similarly long subsubsection title that should also span more than one line, which it does as it's very long}

\end{document}
```

Ideally, the titles in the TOC would automatically be truncated wordwise such that they just fit on one line, but a solution with a fixed width or even a fixed number of characters would be OK as well.

Bonus requirement: I'm also coloring the titles to indicate the status of the respective section, i.e., a solution that also works with titles wrapped in `\textcolor{...}{...}` (or allows to set the color by means of an optional argument or so) would be great.

Comment: I think it's easier to do if you use a guard to mark where you want the split, something like `\subsection{This is a long \splithere subsection title}`. Do you want an answer with that?

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik Yes, please, that's already much better than the manual "solution" in my example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This solution uses a dummy guard token `\splithere` to get the ToC material from the rest of the section title:

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\def\DefSplitSection#1#2{%
  \def#1{\split@startsection#2}%
}
\def\split@startsection#1#2{%
  \split@section@aux#1#2\splithere\@nil
}
\def\split@section@aux#1#2\splithere#3\@nil{%
  \if\relax\detokenize{#3}\relax
    \expandafter\@firstoftwo
  \else
    \expandafter\@secondoftwo
  \fi
    {#1{#2}}%
    {#1[#2]{#2#3}}%
}
\let\splithere\@empty
\makeatother

\DefSplitSection\splitsection\section
\DefSplitSection\splitsubsection\subsection
\DefSplitSection\splitsubsubsection\subsubsection

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{What I have}

\splitsubsection{This is an insanely long subsection title that is supposed to span \splithere multiple lines, which it does because it's insanely long}
\splitsubsubsection{This is a similarly long subsubsection title that should \splithere also span more than one line, which it does as it's very long}

\section{What I want}

\subsection[This is an insanely long subsection title that is supposed to span\ldots]{This is an insanely long subsection title that is supposed to span multiple lines, which it does because it's insanely long}
\subsubsection[This is a similarly long subsubsection title that should\ldots]{This is a similarly long subsubsection title that should also span more than one line, which it does as it's very long}

\end{document}
```

If no `\splithere` is used then the behaviour is the same as the standard sectioning command. Beware that this variant doesn't work with the optional `*` (it would be pointless, because this one doesn't write to the ToC) and doesn't work with the optional `[...]` argument (also pointless, because it already defines the optional argument internally).

---

Edit: With color support in an optional argument:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\makeatletter
\def\DefSplitSection#1#2{%
  \def#1{\split@startsection#2}%
}
\def\split@startsection#1{%
  \let\split@color@cmd\@empty
  \@ifnextchar[%]
    {\split@color@startsection#1}%
    {\split@actually@startsection#1}%
}
\def\split@color@startsection#1[#2]{%
  \def\split@color@cmd{\color{#2}}%
  \split@actually@startsection#1%
}
\def\split@actually@startsection#1#2{%
  \split@section@aux#1#2\splithere\@nil
}
\def\split@section@aux#1#2\splithere#3\@nil{%
  \if\relax\detokenize{#3}\relax
    \expandafter\@firstoftwo
  \else
    \expandafter\@secondoftwo
  \fi
    {#1{\split@color@cmd#2}}%
    {#1[\split@color@cmd#2]{\split@color@cmd#2#3}}%
}
\let\splithere\@empty
\makeatother

\DefSplitSection\splitsection\section
\DefSplitSection\splitsubsection\subsection
\DefSplitSection\splitsubsubsection\subsubsection

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{What I have}

\splitsubsection[blue]{This is an insanely long subsection title that is supposed to span \splithere multiple lines, which it does because it's insanely long}
\splitsubsubsection{This is a similarly long subsubsection title that should \splithere also span more than one line, which it does as it's very long}

\section{What I want}

\subsection[This is an insanely long subsection title that is supposed to span\ldots]{This is an insanely long subsection title that is supposed to span multiple lines, which it does because it's insanely long}
\subsubsection[This is a similarly long subsubsection title that should\ldots]{This is a similarly long subsubsection title that should also span more than one line, which it does as it's very long}

\end{document}
```

Comment: What is `\@nil` definition? Like `\null`?

Comment: @Sigur No, `\@nil` is undefined (or in this case could be defined to anything). It's just a guard macro, just like `\splithere` that is very unlikely to appear in a section title. It could be `\p@tat@es` :) TeX will just look for it when grabbing the delimited argument to `\split@section@aux` (search for "TeX delimited arguments" to learn more). `\null` is defined as `\hbox{}`. It could be used instead of `\@nil` above, but I think it's less likely that someone will write `\@nil` in a section title, so I used it instead.

Comment: Thanks a lot, works great! One issue I ran into: I'm coloring the titles to indicate the status of the section, which breaks the splitting (`\splithere` is not recognized inside a `\textcolor{...}{...}`). I unsuccessfully tried to add the color as an optional argument (e.g., `\splitsubsection[red]{...}`), but at least managed to add the color as an additional mandatory argument (e.g., `\splitsubsection{black}{...}`). If you could add such an optional argument (provided it's not too difficult), that would be great! I'll add the color as a bonus requirement to the question.

Comment: @flotzilla Done. You can't just wrap the section title in `\textcolor` because when TeX is looking for the `\splithere`, it will respect brace groups. More generally, the `\splithere` cannot appear inside any pair of `{...}`, or it won't work. In this specific case you could've used `\color{...}` instead and it would have worked.

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik Thanks, works like a charm! Should've thought of `\color` instead of `\textcolor`, though...